# Get the max of the average for each group

Tags: powerbi, dax

have the following table :

```
EmpId DeptId WeekNumber Month NumberofCalls

1     3      4          1     34

2     3      2          3     59
```

I created a measure to calculate the average of number of calls :

```
AvgCalls = AVG('MyTable'[NumberofCalls])
```

now I want to get the max average calls by month, week.

I will be having 3 filters :

Month
Week
Once I select all of them, the result in the histogram bar will be the employee having the max average calls.

Once I select the Month and the Week I want the histogram to display the code of the Employee (W1,W2,W3...) having the maximum average, in my case I get the following result all the employees but not the employee having the max average.

[image]

Comment: Increase the number of rows in the example dataset to about 10 or so. And include your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I tested it with some random datasets, Here is my data:

```
EmpId   DeptId  WeekNumber  Month   NumberofCalls
Emp01    3          W4         1        34
Emp01    3          W2         3        59
Emp02    3          W5         4        68
Emp02    3          W6         4        76
Emp03    3          W10        5        90
Emp04    4          W10        6        98
Emp04    4          W11        6        45
Emp05    4          W12        7        56
Emp06    4          W13        7        23
Emp07    4          W15        9        45
Emp08    4          W34        8        56
Emp09    4          W52        8        44
Emp05    4          W36        9        23
Emp01    4          W17        10       51
Emp02    4          W23        9        67
Emp06    4          W29        11       28
Emp05    4          W34        12       34
Emp07    4          W41        11       21
Emp04    4          W37        12       33
```

I wrote this measure using Iterator Function (ADDCOLUMNS):

```
MaxAverageEmployer = 
VAR TAvgCalls = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(MyTable,MyTable[EmpId],MyTable[Month ],MyTable[WeekNumber ]),
        "AvgCall",CALCULATE(AVERAGE('MyTable'[NumberofCalls]))
    )
VAR TMaxAvgCalls = 
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        TAvgCalls,
        "MaxAvg",CALCULATE(MAXX(TAvgCalls,[AvgCall]))
    )
VAR MaxEmpID = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    TMaxAvgCalls,
    "MaxEmp",CALCULATE(VALUES(MyTable[EmpId]),FILTER(TMaxAvgCalls,[AvgCall] = [MaxAvg]))
)
RETURN
MAXX(MaxEmpID,[MaxEmp])
```

Here is the part:

It showed nothing when I tried to show it on histogram (or Bar Chart Visual); but It gave me correct values on a table visual:

WeekNumber : I put in on Rows
MonthNumber : I put it on Slicer to filter it!

Here is the final solution, and I hope It is what you are looking for!

[image: Update]

Comment: when I put the measure in the histogram it shows many weeks with your measure instead of showing the week getting the max average

Comment: Can you please share your histogram visual? Hard to judge on my part where it exactly went wrong! You don't need to share actual data. Fake data will also do fine.

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi , Thank you for the histogram visual. Where do you get the code of Employee (W1, W2, W3 etc.. ) from ? Is there a 2nd table (dimension table) in your model?

Comment: They are all in the same table MyTable

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Please check my updated solution above!